# Perform IISRESET if CPU usage above 90%

Tags: iis, batch-file, iisreset

I'm trying to find out how to do an IISRESET if the CPU usage gets above 90%.  I was thinking about using a batch file or something like that, but really I have no clue.

The problem is the CPU usage gets to 99%, the machine slows down and the only way to get the website working again is to log onto the machine and manually perform an IISRESET, I'm trying to find out if there is a way to automate that so that when the CPU usage get to around 95% the IISRESET will happen.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell script will do that:

```
if ((Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples[0].CookedValue -gt 90) { &iisreset }
```